# How to handle combined and split variables in dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have data (currenty in csv) that contains one variable with events (may be empty or contain up to 30 event codes separated by whitespace) and then event date for each of the listed events in separate variables ED1, ED2, ED3...

To get anything useful out of this data I need to be able to find the date for each event. My approach would be to split the event variable into new rows but I'm troubled by how to get the dates correct. (I'm using R since I will use it to analyze data later but was thinking maybe switching to SQL to manage the data).

Sample data with only up to 5 events for simplicity:

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                 E = c("FTT JAD AHN TKZ","", "JAD FTT", "AJN", "TKZ AHD"),
                 ED1 = as.Date(c("2016-04-01","","2014-12-31","2019-05-15","2005-05-04")),
                 ED2 = as.Date(c("2009-06-18","","2007-11-12","","2004-04-09")),
                 ED3 = as.Date(c("2004-09-19","","","","")),
                 ED4 = as.Date(c("2012-07-15","","","","")),
                 ED5 = as.Date(NA))
# New variable with all dates
df %>%
  unite(ED, ED1:ED5, sep=" ", na.rm=T) -> df

# Separate rows
df %>%
  separate_rows(E,ED,sep=" ") -> df
```

This works for this sample dataset but when I try to apply it to my data I get an error:

```
Error: Incompatible lengths: 4, 2.
```

If I'm correct, this means that `E` and `ED` splits into different numbers of rows. So I thought the dataset was missing data. I tried to verify this with:

```
df %>% 
  unite(ED,ED1:ED5,sep=" ", na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(E = strsplit(E," "), ED = strsplit(ED," ")) %>% 
  filter(length(E) != length(ED))

[1] ID E  ED
<0 rows>
```

However, if I try to `separate_rows()` on `E` or `ED` separately I get different number of rows. And this is where I got stuck.

**Additional question:**
In another dataframe I would like to add a boolean for every `ID` if that `ID` has attended a particular event type in between two dates or not based on this dataframe. Each `ID` can occur multiple times in the event dataframe and each ID can have attended the same type of event multiple times.

Comment: The solution you have got strikes me as fine. Please provide a minimal data set that produces the problem.

Comment: I will try to do that. My dataset contains some information I cannot share so I will see if I can redact and still produce the error.

Comment: @Morgan your testing method is flawed use `lengths` instead of `length`

Comment: Thanks, I realised that and tested instead with `for (i in 1:length(df$ID)) {if (length(df$E[[i]]) != length(df$ED[i]])) print(i)}` which returned several rows with missing event dates. `lengths` of course worked even better. For these rows I'd like to leave the date blank, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is clearly rising from the fact that the spaces separating your `E` values are inferior in number to those in `ED`. To account for this you may just split your `E` column and pad the values with empty strings.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.2

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                 E = c("FTT JAD AHN TKZ","", "JAD FTT", "AJN", "TKZ AHD"),
                 ED1 = as.Date(c("2016-04-01","","2014-12-31","2019-05-15","2005-05-04")),
                 ED2 = as.Date(c("2009-06-18","","2007-11-12","","2004-04-09")),
                 ED3 = as.Date(c("2004-09-19","","","","")),
                 ED4 = as.Date(c("2012-07-15","","","","")),
                 ED5 = as.Date(NA),stringsAsFactors=F)
# testing 
df %>% 
  mutate(E = strsplit(E," ")) %>% 
  # change 5 to 30 if you want to use this code on your data
  filter(lengths(E) != 5)
#>   ID                  E        ED1        ED2        ED3        ED4  ED5
#> 1  1 FTT, JAD, AHN, TKZ 2016-04-01 2009-06-18 2004-09-19 2012-07-15 <NA>
#> 2  2                          <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA>
#> 3  3           JAD, FTT 2014-12-31 2007-11-12       <NA>       <NA> <NA>
#> 4  4                AJN 2019-05-15       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA>
#> 5  5           TKZ, AHD 2005-05-04 2004-04-09       <NA>       <NA> <NA>

df %>% 
   mutate( E=lapply(strsplit(E," "), function(x) c(x, rep("", 5-length(x))) )) -> df.split 

### First method keeps numerical format for date and NAs
df.split %>% 
    nest(ED=starts_with("ED"))  %>% 
    mutate(ED=lapply(ED, function(x) unlist(x[1,], use.names=FALSE))) %>%
    unnest(c(E, ED))
#> # A tibble: 25 x 3
#>       ID E        ED
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1     1 "FTT" 16892
#>  2     1 "JAD" 14413
#>  3     1 "AHN" 12680
#>  4     1 "TKZ" 15536
#>  5     1 ""       NA
#>  6     2 ""       NA
#>  7     2 ""       NA
#>  8     2 ""       NA
#>  9     2 ""       NA
#> 10     2 ""       NA
#> # … with 15 more rows

### Second method Everything is a string
df.split %>%
  unite(ED,ED1:ED5,sep=" ", na.rm=T)%>%
  mutate( ED = strsplit(ED," ")) %>%
  unnest(c(E, ED))
#> # A tibble: 25 x 3
#>       ID E     ED   
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>
#>  1     1 "FTT" 16892
#>  2     1 "JAD" 14413
#>  3     1 "AHN" 12680
#>  4     1 "TKZ" 15536
#>  5     1 ""    NA   
#>  6     2 ""    NA   
#>  7     2 ""    NA   
#>  8     2 ""    NA   
#>  9     2 ""    NA   
#> 10     2 ""    NA   
#> # … with 15 more rows
```

## Full on tidy way

```
df%>% 
    separate(E, into=paste0("E", 1:5), fill="right", sep=" ") %>%
    unite(E, E1:E5,sep=" ") %>%
    unite(ED, ED1:ED5,sep=" ") %>%
    mutate(E=strsplit(E," "), ED=strsplit(ED," ")) %>%
    unnest(c(E,ED)) %>% mutate(ED=as.Date(ED)) %>% filter(!is.na(ED))
#>      ID E     ED        
#>   <int> <chr> <date>     
#> 1     1 FTT   2016-04-01
#> 2     1 JAD   2009-06-18
#> 3     1 AHN   2004-09-19
#> 4     1 TKZ   2012-07-15
#> 5     3 JAD   2014-12-31
#> 6     3 FTT   2007-11-12
#> 7     4 AJN   2019-05-15
#> 8     5 TKZ   2005-05-04
#> 9     5 AHD   2004-04-09
```

Comment: Using `na.rm=T` in `unite` does not generate more values in the ED column but skips the `NA` dates. My testing was, as you pointed out, flawed (as mentioned in the comment above), but my understanding is that the problem arose because some rows had missing event dates. Would it be possible to generate separate rows for all event codes, dates for those that has dates and where date is not available `lengths(E) > lengths(ED)` instead fill with `NA`?

Comment: @Morgan from what I understood lengths(E) could never be superior to lengths(ED) as at maximum there would be 30 events. Am I right in this ?

Comment: `lengths(E)` can be superior to `lengths(ED)` if no date is available in the `ED1, ED2, ED3...` I have no cases with `NA` in `E` but 2.5% have `NA` in `ED`.

Comment: I can't see the contention you have I just retried the code with NAs in all dates and it's working fine.

Comment: @Morgan a solution would be to remove the na.rm. to force ED to be of length 30. this way the above solution will do just fine

Comment: for my laptop na.rm didn't change the count of the ED vector

Comment: In my example df, with the test you suggested `df %>% unite(ED,ED1:ED5,sep=" ", na.rm=T) %>% mutate(E = strsplit(E," "), ED = strsplit(ED," ")) %>% filter(lengths(E) == lengths(ED))` returns all rows but with `na.rm=F` returns zero rows. The number of values for ED changes but not for E since it already has a fix number of values.

Comment: In any case, your post helped put me in the right direction with the correct test. Your solution also works but generates new rows with empty `E` field which, albeit easily corrected afterwards, is unwanted. The optimal solution for me I think would be to do `separate_rows(E,ED,sep=" ")` where `lengths(E) == lengths(ED)` and `separate_rows(E,sep=" ")` where `lengths(E) != lengths(ED)` but I can't figure out how to do this elegantly. Your solution followed by `filter(E != "")` works though.

Comment: @Morgan for the data you have provided setting `na.rm=F` changes nothing (in my laptop at least) as the problem is from the missing event ids that are not included in the data, that's why I pad them. Plus I think it's better to filter after than split the process into two calls as we now that the tidyverse syntax is non-efficient. each time the data is copied and so on. so the less calls the better. I've concocted a tidy way to do it it's in the new edit.